# Change button appearance on click Angular2

Tags: angular, button, typescript

I've got a button element in an `*ngFor` array in my Angular2 app.

The structure of the button is:

```
<button>
   <span class="price">{{ product.price }}</span>

   <span class="text"> Add me! </span>
</button>
```

When I click on it I need to remove the text inside the span `.text` and put smth else inside, say `<span class="text"> Added! </span>` not display the `.price` span interpolation.

I tried to make it in the following way:

`<button [textContent]="isPressed? 'Added!' : 'Add me' "></button>`
And declare the corresponding property in the Class like:

```
private isPressed = false;
```

It works fine, but the problem is that it changes all buttons simultaneously, and I need to change only the clicked one.

What is the correct way to make it working properly?

Comment: instead of `isPressed` use a semantic variable like `product.isAdded`. This way the state of the button is bound to the product in question.

Comment: Why it's not working with isPressed, but works well with isAdded?
Please, submit your answer thus I could vote for your help

Comment: The reason is not the wording, but the `product`, which refers to a specific object the button relates to. There's many products (that's why you need the loop) and therefore you have the state saved per product. Each button shows the state of one particular product. If you were using a generic variable like `isPressed` there is only one and all buttons are watching it. The answers below show you how to adjust your code. Upvote them :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably store added products somewhere anyway. Use this information to display proper button label, e.g.:

```
<button (click)='addProduct(product)'>
   <span class="price" *ngIf="!isProductAdded(product)">{{ product.price }}</span>
   <span class="text">{{ isProductAdded(product) ? 'Added!' : 'Add me!'}}</span>
</button>
```

`addProduct(product)` and `isProductAdded(product)` would need to be defined in your Component.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments you should keep selected flag on product item itself. This way you can do something like this in template:

```
<button (click)="selectProduct(product)">
  <span class="price">{{ product.price }}</span>
  <span class="text">{{ product.selected ? 'Added!' : 'Add me!' }}</span>
</button>
```

And in controller:

```
selectProduct(product) {
  // You probable want to make HTTP request here to save product
  // and on success set selected flag, or do something else..
  product.selected = !product.selected
}
```